# Ignoring a primary key in a SQL delete where exists statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Last CTE based SQL question for today, I promise!

I have a CTE and it returns a couple of rows:

```
WITH myCte AS
( ... )
SELECT 123 AS PersonId, DeviceId 
FROM myCte
```

would return:

```
 PersonId | DeviceId
 ---------+---------
     123     4
     123     8
```

I tried to use the results in a delete statement so I could get rid of the respective rows in *another table* `PersonHasDevice`

```
pk | PersonId | DeviceId
---+----------+---------
1      123        4         - to delete
2      123        5
3      123        8         - to delete
4      991        8
```

So I appended the delete bit to the CTE select:

```
WITH myCte AS 
( ... )
DELETE FROM PersonHasDevice 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 123 AS PersonId, DeviceId FROM myCte)
```

But this just deletes **everything** from the `PersonHasDevice` table.

I'm not sure if it's because I'm not taking into account the PK on the table - but then if that were the case surely it shouldn't delete anything?!

Comment: Above query deleted every thing because where clause always return TRUE. If ```myCte``` has no rows then where clause returns FALSE. So, from the above query has two possibilities are everything delete or nothing delete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "connect" the CTE to your table.  You can do this using `exists` or using a `join`:

```
with  myCte as ( ... )
delete phd
    from PersonHasDevice phd join
         myCte
         on phd.PersonId = myCte.PersonId and
            phd.DeviceId = myCte.DeviceId
```

**Edit by OP**

Just reiterating that the hardcoded value `123` in my original query is easily substituted here:

```
with  myCte as ( ... )
delete phd
    from PersonHasDevice phd join
         myCte
         on phd.PersonId = 123 and
            phd.DeviceId = myCte.DeviceId
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, my job would have taken two days longer without your help today :D -

Comment: Since `PersonId` is not used to join, `phd.PersonId = 123` could even be extracted into a separate where clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax if you want to use `EXISTS`:

```
WITH myCte AS (.....)
DELETE p FROM PersonHasDevice p
WHERE p.PersonId = 123 
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM myCte m
  WHERE p.DeviceId = m.DeviceId
);
```